# makehuman gives "ImportError: No module named numpy"

Tags: kde, python, slackware

I installed 1.0.0 on slackware 14.1 makehuman 64bit slackbuilds through the site, but the makehuman does not open, the program appears in the KDE menu but does not open.
I do not know why it happens, the only dependence was a PyOpenGL library and I installed this library. what may have caused this problem?

error:

```
bash-4.2# exit
exit
bash-4.2# makehuman
Initialized logging
VERSION: 1.0.0
SHORT VERSION: v1.0.0
BASEMESH VERSION: hm08
IS BUILT (FROZEN): No
IS RELEASE VERSION: Yes
HOME LOCATION: /root
SYS.VERSION: 2.7.5 (default, May 29 2013, 02:28:51)  [GCC 4.8.0]
SYS.PLATFORM: linux2
PLATFORM.MACHINE: x86_64
PLATFORM.PROCESSOR: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+
PLATFORM.UNAME.RELEASE: 3.10.17
PLATFORM.LINUX_DISTRIBUTION: Slackware  14.1 
Could not create debug dump
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/makehuman/makehuman.py", line 284, in debug_dump
debugdump.dump.reset()
  File "./lib/debugdump.py", line 98, in reset
import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/makehuman/makehuman.py", line 362, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/share/makehuman/makehuman.py", line 347, in main
import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the numpy module to make it work:

```
File "/usr/share/makehuman/makehuman.py", line 347, in main
import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

In Slackware just [download the numpy](http://pkgs.org/slackware-14.1/slacky-x86_64/numpy-1.8.0-x86_64-1sl.txz.html) package and install it:

```
upgradepkg --install-new numpy-1.8.0-i486-1_rlw.txz
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked now. I need to learn to pay more attention to the error messages, there is always a solution! Thanks!!!

Comment: @PattersonSilva It would help if you [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/145982) this if it solved the problem